# NoReverseMatch on Django even when kwargs are provided

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-1.8, django-1.11

The Django cant resovle the url, even though the expected kwarg is provided.

Here is root urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    url(r'^(?P<domain>\w+)', include('frontend.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is frontend urls.py:
from django.conf.urls import include,patterns,url

```
from . import views
from .views import MyprofileView
from .views import SuccessView
from .views import CompanyView
from .views import SubscriptionView


from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'/success(/?)$', SuccessView.as_view(), name='success'),
    url(r'/subscribe(/?)$', SubscriptionView.as_view(), name='subscribe'),
    url(r'^(/?)$', MyprofileView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'/api/v1/', include('cpprofile.api.urls')),
    url(r'/product', include('product_information.urls')),
    url(r'/corporations/(?P<company>\d+)$', CompanyView.as_view(), name='company_page'),
    url(r'^/(?P<subscription>\w+)/product/pay/return/(?P<amount>\d+)/(?P<currency>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)?$',
        views.payment_return, name='subscription_product_payment_return'),
)
```

And here is how I am trying to reverse call it in view.py MyprofileView:

```
context['subscribe_url'] = redirect('subscribe', kwargs={'domain': 'up'})
```

What could be wrong here?

Thanks

---

### UPDATE 1

Here is the error I am getting:

django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'subscribe' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'domain': 'up'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<domain>\\w+)/subscribe(/?)$']
```

Comment: There is no capturing group named as `domain` in pattern `/subscribe(/?)$`.. and what's `(/?)`?

Comment: @AamirAdnan It is for trailing slash, but I tried removing it too, it doesnt matter, it still doesnt resolve.

Comment: @SachinKukreja if you look back at the question, I have provided two urls, one is root url conf, where domain is captured and second is frontend urls.py where subscribe is.

Comment: @Maverick your `subscribe` url does not expect any keyword param.

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov look at my root urls.py it does expect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unpack the `kwargs`.

**Solution**:

```
kwargs = {'domain': 'up'}
redirect('app_name:subscribe', **kwargs)
```

EDIT: This will work, no need to change the url.
EDIT2: Prepend app's name and a colon to url name. This finds the url in the app namespace.

Ref: [Redirect in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: No, it is a requirement of the project, cant change the url.

Comment: nope, doesnt work, kwargs = {'domain': 'up'}
            context['subscribe_url'] = redirect('subscribe', **kwargs) and between it is no different than redirect('subscribe', kwargs={'domain': 'up'})

Comment: ok, but in any case it didnt help, I have updated with the error I am getting.

Comment: I tried it earlier too, and now as well after you updated, nope, still it doesnt work with namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because of the `(/?)`. That captures either `''` or `'/'`. So you have to pass that as a non-keyword argument:

```
redirect('subscribe', '/', domain='up')
```

So this is in addition to what Sachin Kukreja says.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesnt help, it gives: `ValueError

ValueError: Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()!` I even tried `redirect('subscribe', '/', **kwargs)` but no success same error.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you couldn't do that. In that case, you have three options: try if `/?` without  the () works (I have no idea), give the / a name `(?P<slash>/?)`, or use the redirect middleware everyone else uses to deal with paths with or without slashes...

Comment: Actually I removed that (/?) and it resolves now BUT with Sachins solution, I am still interested on how that kwargs work for him rather than we explicitly providing it.

Comment: If you add a / add the end, Django should redirect URLs without slashes that aren't found to the equivalent with a slash automatically.

Comment: For reverse you have to pass kwargs=, for redirect **kwargs.

Comment: It gives this error : `TypeError: reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'domain'` which I know why, but I am using FormView CBV, dont know where to pass that domain object. any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reverse to get the correct URL, and then redirect to that.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

return redirect(reverse('subscribe', kwargs={'domain': 'up'}))
```

In your case, where you seem to be trying to assign the url to a context variable, you shouldn't use redirect at all. Reverse resolves the URL, redirect returns a response.

```
context['subscribe_url'] = reverse('subscribe', kwargs={'domain': 'up'})
```

Might also want to follow best practices with your urlconf for consistency, namely end all patterns with '/', but don't start any with '/'. As you do for most of them in the root config:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), <-- good
```